# In Lies Incorporated, what is the significance of beaming a non-lie into Applebaum's head

Tags: philip-k-dick

The book Lies Incorporated features the universe's premier intelligence corporation "Lies Incorporated", a *nearly* omnipotent corporation, with many strange offshoot functions. One of these functions is (presumed) to beam misinformation directly into the minds of the sleeping populace. There is a considerable amount of time in this book dedicated to a scene describing the operation of a malfunctioning computer within the ranks of Lies Incorporated. This computer suffers a malfunction in the beaming process and beams information about a rat into Applebaum's head, information which isn't a lie. Is there any significance to this?

Comment: This is very related to your other question. It is very possible, maybe even probable, that this event causes the "Abbas" character to communicate with Applebaum.

Comment: @clara diaz sanchez i tried asking them together before, but it was closed because users didn't see the connection.

Comment: Yes, there is a policy on the site to ask just one question in each post. Here though the questions overlap so much that they might be considered duplicates of each other. There is nothing wrong with that, but one may be deleted. If you want, you could delete one question yourself, just to avoid unnecessary duplication.